# How to obtain the best fit values of `a` and `b`

Tags: plotting

here is set of data.

```
{{-6.28319, 3.06707}, {-6.22035, 2.96473}, {-6.15752, 
  3.18398}, {-6.09469, 3.22623}, {-6.03186, 2.58625}, {-5.96903, 
  2.4081}, {-5.90619, 2.30268}, {-5.84336, 1.75846}, {-5.78053, 
  1.53609}, {-5.7177, 1.67376}, {-5.65487, 1.08757}, {-5.59203, 
  0.887877}, {-5.5292, 0.764236}, {-5.46637, 0.782493}, {-5.40354, 
  0.666159}, {-5.34071, 0.469877}, {-5.27788, 0.353436}, {-5.21504, 
  0.32059}, {-5.15221, 0.282072}, {-5.08938, 0.224285}, {-5.02655, 
  0.198952}, {-4.96372, 0.180834}, {-4.90088, 0.165968}, {-4.83805, 
  0.172037}, {-4.77522, 0.167065}, {-4.71239, 0.150082}, {-4.64956, 
  0.153673}, {-4.58673, 0.186473}, {-4.52389, 0.166376}, {-4.46106, 
  0.19644}, {-4.39823, 0.213121}, {-4.3354, 0.234954}, {-4.27257, 
  0.295397}, {-4.20973, 0.329096}, {-4.1469, 0.354295}, {-4.08407, 
  0.427717}, {-4.02124, 0.508824}, {-3.95841, 0.684087}, {-3.89557, 
  0.737755}, {-3.83274, 0.970972}, {-3.76991, 1.06964}, {-3.70708, 
  1.26858}, {-3.64425, 1.57755}, {-3.58142, 1.89527}, {-3.51858, 
  2.00068}, {-3.45575, 2.73965}, {-3.39292, 2.58552}, {-3.33009, 
  3.53549}, {-3.26726, 2.9681}, {-3.20442, 3.20238}, {-3.14159, 
  3.00147}, {-3.07876, 2.96773}, {-3.01593, 2.88376}, {-2.9531, 
  3.52059}, {-2.89027, 2.60561}, {-2.82743, 2.43369}, {-2.7646, 
  2.09201}, {-2.70177, 1.75783}, {-2.63894, 1.51186}, {-2.57611, 
  1.2753}, {-2.51327, 1.06948}, {-2.45044, 0.946446}, {-2.38761, 
  0.735844}, {-2.32478, 0.653638}, {-2.26195, 0.672593}, {-2.19911, 
  0.435117}, {-2.13628, 0.374499}, {-2.07345, 0.388105}, {-2.01062, 
  0.307276}, {-1.94779, 0.240313}, {-1.88496, 0.198942}, {-1.82212, 
  0.237058}, {-1.75929, 0.168411}, {-1.69646, 0.205188}, {-1.63363, 
  0.196649}, {-1.5708, 0.178861}, {-1.50796, 0.151156}, {-1.44513, 
  0.156568}, {-1.3823, 0.171041}, {-1.31947, 0.180429}, {-1.25664, 
  0.209893}, {-1.19381, 0.250246}, {-1.13097, 0.257486}, {-1.06814, 
  0.387131}, {-1.00531, 0.356676}, {-0.942478, 0.421306}, {-0.879646, 
  0.505373}, {-0.816814, 0.618249}, {-0.753982, 0.742413}, {-0.69115, 
  0.96845}, {-0.628319, 1.09753}, {-0.565487, 1.29364}, {-0.502655, 
  1.54678}, {-0.439823, 1.74159}, {-0.376991, 2.03285}, {-0.314159, 
  2.30415}, {-0.251327, 2.49323}, {-0.188496, 2.70047}, {-0.125664, 
  2.92666}, {-0.0628319, 3.147}, {8.88178*10^-16, 
  3.00009}, {0.0628319, 2.96506}, {0.125664, 3.69675}, {0.188496, 
  2.73919}, {0.251327, 2.59297}, {0.314159, 2.28973}, {0.376991, 
  2.37359}, {0.439823, 1.77724}, {0.502655, 1.49895}, {0.565487, 
  1.27447}, {0.628319, 1.25117}, {0.69115, 0.88666}, {0.753982, 
  0.907868}, {0.816814, 0.652895}, {0.879646, 0.512775}, {0.942478, 
  0.459046}, {1.00531, 0.362171}, {1.06814, 0.315906}, {1.13097, 
  0.337593}, {1.19381, 0.225286}, {1.25664, 0.200794}, {1.31947, 
  0.18601}, {1.3823, 0.176216}, {1.44513, 0.172146}, {1.50796, 
  0.15203}, {1.5708, 0.152544}, {1.63363, 0.162791}, {1.69646, 
  0.158226}, {1.75929, 0.19074}, {1.82212, 0.179813}, {1.88496, 
  0.231289}, {1.94779, 0.282846}, {2.01062, 0.273322}, {2.07345, 
  0.347488}, {2.13628, 0.464175}, {2.19911, 0.517131}, {2.26195, 
  0.558927}, {2.32478, 0.610471}, {2.38761, 0.795847}, {2.45044, 
  0.890453}, {2.51327, 1.07052}, {2.57611, 1.37719}, {2.63894, 
  1.63123}, {2.70177, 2.31678}, {2.7646, 2.58171}, {2.82743, 
  2.25627}, {2.89027, 2.49236}, {2.9531, 2.73203}, {3.01593, 
  3.18419}, {3.07876, 3.41248}, {3.14159, 3.10005}, {3.20442, 
  2.96473}, {3.26726, 3.63233}, {3.33009, 3.05719}, {3.39292, 
  2.74941}, {3.45575, 2.25327}, {3.51858, 2.02879}, {3.58142, 
  2.24308}, {3.64425, 1.66423}, {3.70708, 1.27166}, {3.76991, 
  1.1742}, {3.83274, 1.02115}, {3.89557, 0.735588}, {3.95841, 
  0.797138}, {4.02124, 0.517385}, {4.08407, 0.42141}, {4.1469, 
  0.36229}, {4.20973, 0.392941}, {4.27257, 0.265514}, {4.3354, 
  0.291255}, {4.39823, 0.201606}, {4.46106, 0.19618}, {4.52389, 
  0.190342}, {4.58673, 0.156961}, {4.64956, 0.185436}, {4.71239, 
  0.162217}, {4.77522, 0.17993}, {4.83805, 0.161685}, {4.90088, 
  0.166415}, {4.96372, 0.189599}, {5.02655, 0.205805}, {5.08938, 
  0.234122}, {5.15221, 0.268397}, {5.21504, 0.303497}, {5.27788, 
  0.412239}, {5.34071, 0.477834}, {5.40354, 0.519274}, {5.46637, 
  0.618945}, {5.5292, 0.748803}, {5.59203, 0.95291}, {5.65487, 
  1.06411}, {5.7177, 1.29203}, {5.78053, 1.88471}, {5.84336, 
  1.89622}, {5.90619, 2.19759}, {5.96903, 2.55314}, {6.03186, 
  2.49536}, {6.09469, 2.78078}, {6.15752, 3.33169}, {6.22035, 
  2.96572}, {6.28319, 3.03594}}
```

this is my code so far.

```
 datanlm = Import["datanonlinear.txt", "Data"];
    lpt = ListPlot[datanlm]
    NonLdataFit = 
     NonlinearModelFit[datanlm, a*Exp[(-b*Sin^2[x]], {a, b}, x]
```

i got the error. maybe i supposed put the range of `a` and `b` ? i tried 
`NonLdataFit = NonlinearModelFit[datanlm, a*Exp[(-b*Sin^2[x]],
  {{a, -6}, {b, 5}}, x]` but return error too.

[image]

with the best fit `a` and `b` values, i want to plot `y=a*Exp[-b*(Sin^2)[x]]` and overlap it on top of the original data points (picture above) to show that both fit nicely to each other.

all help is appreciated. thank you.

Comment: you have a syntax error. It should be `Sin[x]^2`.

Comment: oh my. yes you are correct. im sorry for my silly mistake there. @ubpdqn

Comment: You have serious syntax errors. Here's the fix: `NonlinearModelFit[datanlm, a*Exp[-b*Sin[x]^2], {a, b}, x]`.

Comment: @Nabil we all make mistakes :)

Comment: thank you for point it out. will work it out now @ubpdqn

Comment: In general, you should provide the full error message to make it easier and faster to find and fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a syntax error. `NonlinearModelFit` works in this set without setting initial values. The latter remains important in general, however.

```
f[a_, b_, x_] := a Exp[-b Sin[x]^2]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, f[a, b, x], {a, b}, x]
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]]
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

where `data` is the first list in question.

[image]